# Python webscrape using bs4 skips first item but does the rest the fine

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using this link > https://secure.runescape.com/m=hiscore/ranking?category_type=0&table=0&time_filter=0&date=1589144604901&page=1 and I am trying to scrape all the names listed on this site. However it keeps skipping the first name. How can I fix this? I am searching for the img tag with class avatar.

```
for i in soup.select('img[class*="avatar"]'):
     print (i.get_text().strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a few ways you can grab the names, but here's one that works:

```
for i in soup.select('img.avatar'):
    print(i['alt'])
```

In bs4, you can do tag.class_name, and then you can treat it like a dictionary when getting values like `alt`.

Digging into your code

```
for i in soup.select('img[class*="avatar"]'):
    print(i)
    print("------------------")
    print (i.get_text().strip())
    print("------------------")
```

I see the following output (shortened):

```
<img alt="le me" class="avatar" src="https://secure.runescape.com/m=avatar-rs/le+me/chat.png?w=27&amp;h=27"/>
------------------

------------------
<img alt="L33" class="avatar" src="https://secure.runescape.com/m=avatar-rs/L33/chat.png?w=27&amp;h=27">
L33
<img alt="RuneScape Member" class="memberIcon" src="https://www.runescape.com/img/rs3/hiscores/member-icon.png" title="RuneScape Member"/>
</img>
------------------
L33
------------------
<img alt="Omid" class="avatar" src="https://secure.runescape.com/m=avatar-rs/Omid/chat.png?w=27&amp;h=27">
Omid
<img alt="RuneScape Member" class="memberIcon" src="https://www.runescape.com/img/rs3/hiscores/member-icon.png" title="RuneScape Member"/>
</img>
------------------
Omid
------------------
```

I can't explain why the character's name isn't with the text of the first img tag, but this seems to be an unreliable way of grabbing the names.

Comment: i really need that first name included too :/ i cant tell if its the website or bs4

Comment: @KhalaMan2000 If you follow my method, you get the first name. If you follow your method, then you're going to fail because the website does not report the name in `text` of the `img` tag for the first one. Definitely the website.